# Right SMPS for gate drive in power mosfet

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inverter, gate-driving

I am building a 48v, 2kw sinewave inverter based on EGS002, in order to drive spwm & control circuitry, I need to step down 48v to 12v.

Interestingly I found Hilink's 3w (0.25a) and 10w (0.83a) pcb mount modular smps can work with DC input as low as 35vdc and 51vdc respectively. I am excited to use them.

My question is, power mosfets like IR4110 or FB38N20D or any IGBT can draw more than 1 amps, and my H bridge will have 6 of them. Operating frequency is over 20khz.

I wonder if these modular smps of 0.25 amp rated capacity will be sufficient? They still look big and I have tested, inverter did run smoothly, but at this stage I cannot test using higher loads.

I have seen inverter from other vendors, they use similar type converter (buck ?) to step down 48v, atleast in size comparison, and this hilink 10w smps is huge, but spec still say 0.83amp.

In that case this smps may not be sufficient?

**Edit**

Hilink smps datasheet
HLK-PM12 Ultra-compact module power - Nettigo https://nettigo.pl/attachments/503

Comment: Can you please provide datasheets of these Hilink modules?

Comment: I have edited and put link, according to official spec it runs above 90vac but in tests i found they worked as low as 35vdc

Comment: They are actually very popular, if you google hilink smps, all sellers have them

Comment: What do you mean by "can draw [current]"? Do you mean peak gate drive current? What about average? The power supply only sees the average consumption. Should you be asking about how to calculate gate drive supply current instead? (Which has been answered before I believe.)

Comment: @TimWilliams i see, I will read on how to calculate gate drive current. Thanks. Does gate drive current change with load ?

Comment: Depends on the controller, but not usually by much.

Comment: @TimWilliams ...Great... Thanks for putting me in right direction

Comment: That SMPS specifies input voltage range of 90 to 264 V AC. Where did you read that it could run off low voltage DC?

Comment: @Finbarr true that it specifies 90vac min, but most smps works with dc so when i tested it can be cold started at 35vdc minimum.

Comment: Tested at full load and temperature range? Running devices way, way outside their specifications is never a good idea.

Comment: I have tested 4 pieces many times and at full load :) its a good feature (or bug), but very useful